# R: all variable values are identical

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, data-manipulation

I am using the R programming language.

I created the following data set:

```
  library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

#train data
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,200,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

The following graphs show the distributions of variables "a1" and "b1":

```
hist(a1)
hist(b1)
```

[image]

Now, I am trying to add two columns to this dataset:

- The first column ("cat") will jointly look at "a1" and "b1" and assign them into "3 bins" ("a", "b", "c") based on some random criteria
- The second column ("quant") will calculate the 60th quantile for each "bin", and place this 60th quantile calculation in each row having that "bin"

**1) First Column:**

```
    #random criteria
    random_1 =  runif(1, 0, 100)
    random_2 =  runif(1, 100, 200)
    
    #view plot (with rough outline of desired bins)
    plot(train$a1, train$b1)
```

[image]

```
# attempt to make the first column:
train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_1, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_2, "b", "c")))
```

However, this results in all values of the "cat" column as "a":

```
table(train_data$cat)

 a 
1000
```

**Problem: Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Why is everything appearing as "a"?**

**2) Second Column:**

This is preventing me from properly adding the second column:

```
#convert to factor
train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)

#calculate 60th quantile for "c1" per unique value of "cat":

 train_data%>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  summarise(quant = quantile(c1, prob = c(.6)))
```

Unfortunately, this produces a single value :

```
  cat   quant
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a      647.
```

Whereas I wanted the 60th quantile for "a", "b" and "c" to appear as a column in "train_data" (e.g. in the "train_data" table, any time "cat = a", then "quant = 60th percentile using values c1" , etc.)

Can someone please help me resolve these errors?

Thanks

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code. It gives you the output based on the condition that you have selected. You may need to change the condition for `random_1` and `random_2` according to the distribution of your data.

Comment: @ronak Shah: thank you for your reply! I tried multiple values of "random_1" and "random_2", but the "table" command still shows there is only 1 class of "cat" being created. Also, do you know how to make "quant" as a column within "train_data" instead of a single value? Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to randomly divide the data in 3 groups you can use `cut` -

```
library(dplyr)

train_data %>%
  group_by(cat = cut(a1, 3, labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))) %>%
  summarise(quant = quantile(c1, prob = .6))

#  cat   quant
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1 a      636 
#2 b      650.
#3 c      690.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know if it is possible so that the final table looks something like this? https://imgur.com/a/haoiET8 Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Do you want to calculate quantile for each rowwise value separately? `train_data %>% mutate(cat = cut(a1, 3, labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))) %>%  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(quant = quantile(c_across(a1:c1), prob = .6))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am trying to calculate the quantile for all categories of "cat". In the "cat" column, there should only be 3 unique values. E.g. in the code you provided in the comments,  (first 2 rows) for the same value of "cat = b", the value of "quant" is different (https://imgur.com/a/DfJKkfF). I am trying to keep it the same (e.g. in your original answer, every time "cat = a", then "quant" = 636). Do you know how to fix this? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I see so you want to maintain the rows of the original dataframe by repeating the same quantile values? In my original answer you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise`. `train_data %>%
  group_by(cat = cut(a1, 3, labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))) %>%
  mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = .6))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is starting to look a lot like how it should! Just a question, in the code from your most recent comment : train_data %>%   group_by(cat = cut(a1, 3, labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))) %>%   mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = .6)) ... why does this not use "random_1" and "random_2"? Was I supposed to create the "cat" column before running "train_data %>%   group_by(cat = cut(a1, 3, labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))) %>%   mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = .6))" ? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The purpose of using `random_1` and `random_2` was to create `cat` column right? The problem as mentioned in the comment earlier is that `random_1` and `random_2` do not give you the accurate breaks that you need in your data. For example, for me when I run `train_data %>% filter(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_1)` I get no rows returned and everything is assigned to to `"c"`. Using `cut` we divide the data into 3 groups accurately.

Comment: Thank you for all your help - can you please take a look at this question if you have some time? can you please take a look at this question if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68219695/r-combining-results-from-different-iterations-into-a-table?noredirect=1#comment120569635_68219695 thanks!